# Can images uploaded in the answer become dead after sometime?

Tags: discussion

Please **note** that I didn't add images from some other external source but uploaded screenshots in the answer, i.e. image links are created by stackexchange itself, so how they can become dead after sometime?

Sample answers:

https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/23603/12304

https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/23268/12304

By the way, I understand that images might not render properly in all browsers and text is always better option. But if we have large pdfs (of images) then Google Drive OCR is also not an option to extract the text.

And if I post text from some other translators which are basically short versions (but matches with the original Sanskrit text and Hindi translation as per my knowledge), few users including moderator say that it's not acceptable, see [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/23236/12304).

Comment: You need not to take a screenshot whole chapter, we want answers in text so that all the browsers can read the text. As you said images are not rendered properly on some browsers and imgur is blocked in some countries. So, we should only write answers. Image makes a link like answer. On MSE, there were instances, where the images are not supported. In sample answer 2, I see some two links, two images and a note which is _not_ a very good answer. It is always better to write answers as text.

Comment: "imgur is blocked in some countries" - that's not my problem, this question should go to SE, why they have chosen this source..And if this is the case then it's really problematic..let's say there is an image (picture and not a screenshot of text), then what is the solution for that..for an instance, one user asked who is the goddess in the picture..then how one can ask/answer such questions here..

Comment: What do you mean by  this question should go to SE? You posted it didn't you?  There would no problem for image identification question unless you don't describe the image you posted. People using text browsers willknow by seeing the image description. I saw no users who describe an image here. But we should describe an image. But answers should not contain only image and a link. It is a low quality one.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma I mean you should ask SE Why they use imgur which is blocked in some countries (as you say)..I don't have enough time to extract text from a screenshot so going forward I would rather prefer not to answer if screenshots are not acceptable..please accept my sincere apologies for degrading site's quality..

Comment: And if I post text from some other translators which are basically short.... not acceptable ---- Why not acceptable?.. i myself do that some times.

Comment: It is user's problem. What is the use if your answer sorry _image_ is not visible to users? What is the use if it is not useful to other users?  The site is Q&A @YDS Not questions and images. We want quality here. An image alone is not a good answer. I don't see much effort  posting just a screenshot. Others might agree but no one's forcing you to post answers in a hurry. Take your own time and post a detailed answer in your own words. Copy paste, images answer are not good for the site. Image alone shouldn't be the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`stack.imgur.com`(part of imgur.com) [hosts images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94286) of Stack exchange sites.

[Stackoverflow blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/18/new-image-upload-support/) says:

> Alan Schaaf, the man behind Imgur, generously provided us a
>   network-wide “pro” account that keeps any images hosted through our
>   websites around indefinitely.

So, there won't be any dead links of images hosted to imgur across SE sites in future, unless imgur crashes or goes down temporarily.

Regarding large pdfs, you can split it into small pdfs (say 2-3 pages) and try Google drive OCR.  PDFsam Basic is one good tool which serves this purpose.

Comment: There was an instant were the images are gone. Whole imgur was crashed.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma But i think such crashes are temporary and images will be restored later.

Comment: but still the image is a link like answer. Some images on meta  They might be gone. I have seen some removed images on the MSE. Plus, imgur is blocked in some countries. It is blocked by some office computers due to some reasons. Does adding just an image make an answer good answer? How is it better than a link like answer?

Comment: @Sarvabhouma I didn't say such answers are good or supported them. It is always better to write answers as text.

Comment: It could be useful if you add that in the answer. Because the OP added images and links in their answer instead of quotes.

Comment: The user says he doesn't have much time to write answers and to type. So, he is posting images as the only answer but not as a reference. It would be helpful to say in your answer what you said in the above comment.